# How to specify while using std::vector<Base*> to store Derived*

Tags: c++

```
Class Base{
public:
...
    void do_Something_base();
    string identifier();
    virtual void derived1_specific() {};  // nothing relevant to Base
    virtual int derived2_specific(int) {};
};

Class Derived1:public Base {
public:
...
    string identifier();
    void derived1_specific();
};

Class Derived2:public Base {
public:
... 
    string identifier();
    int derived2_specific();
};


int main() {
   vector<Base*> owner;
   /* push back some Derived1* & Derived2* to owner */

   for (int i = 0; i < owner.size(); i++)
       if (owner->identifier() == "d1")
           owner->derived1_specific(int) 
}
```

I have a larger program, that's the mechanics that make me confused. Should I write virtual function for every derived class? But this is very tedious. 
I need to get and set some specific members, do some specific function in different child class. What is a smarter way or common way to do this?
thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing or asking. Please provide some example scenarios of what should happen, what you currently do, and what the problem is. Anyway - Virtual functions exist to despatch based on dynamic type. Manually doing this yourself using an identifier and `if`/`switch`/`case` type despatch is _far more_ tedious. And why are you implementing multiple functions that do `nothing()`? Do they somehow do _different_ nothings? With virtual functions, you can implement an empty `nothing()` in the `Base` and then never once have to override it unless the `Derived` does _something_

Comment: @underscore_d：what you say is just what I mean. wait until I modify the question a bit

Comment: If you need functionality not present in base then you could do a static_cast to the correct type as specified by "identifier". This avoids pointless virtual functions.

Comment: @JamesElderfield: thanks! is this the common way to deal with this situation, or should I just avoid this kind of style?

Comment: Aside: Your base class contains a non virtual `string identifier(string&);` and your derived classes define non-virtual `string identifier();` : W/O guessing what it actually does: *Looks extremely brittle.*

Comment: @PeterLai It is certainly something I have used but not convinced it is great design, see this [code review post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/casting-base-to-derived-class-according-to-a-type-flag). Alternatively look up the visitor pattern.

Comment: @MartinBa sorry about that ... modified

Comment: @PeterLai The function ```virtual int derived2_specific(int) {};``` needs the integer or you just forgot it? Because when you override the function you don't have the param.

Comment: @PeterLai Look up the CRTP, which provides static polymorphism without requiring you to write horrible conditional cascades at each call site.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks! I am going to learn CRTP next week in my course. that would be a good lead.

Comment: @PeterLai Cool, it's a great pattern! Although as Francesco has pointed out, it might not cover situations where you need to call different functions based on type. It's more for simulating virtual functions while avoiding the associated overhead (vtable space, lookup time) - which although the overhead is usually insignificant, why spend it when you don't have to! It also enables some other cool things that I'm sure you'll learn about :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try really hard to find a common signature for the subclass-specific methods and then create one virtual function in the base class that can be called without some kind of ID-function.

Sometimes this can be achieved by passing some additional information needed for the subclass-specific function to the derived class's constructor, the common method could then be called e.g.

```
virtual void doClassSpecificStuff();
```

that uses member variables of your derived classes.

If you truly need differing return types etc, you might not want to inherit from a common ancestor OR not store all objects in the same container. Maybe composition works better than inheritance in your context (some class *has-a* specific worker object instead of *is-a*).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I erased the virtual solution since OP clarified that he needs to pass different parameters.

Since you have a way to know its actual type, there is nothing wrong in just casting to it, and then using it as that type:

```
Class Base{
public:
...
    void do_Something_base();
    string identifier();
};

Class Derived1:public Base {
public:
...
    string identifier();
    void TakeTwoInts(int x, int y);
};

Class Derived2:public Base {
public:
... 
    string identifier();
    const char* ReturnAString();    
};


int main() {
   vector<Base*> owner;
   /* push back some Derived1* & Derived2* to owner */

   for (int i = 0; i < owner.size(); i++)
       switch(owner[i]->identifier())
         {
           case "d1": 
            {
              Derived1* d1 = static_cast<Derived1*>(owner[i]);
              d1->TakeTwoInts(1,2);
              break;
             }
            case "d2":
             {
              Derived2* d2 = static_cast<Derived2*>(owner[i]); 
              printf("%s",d2->ReturnAString());
              break;
             }
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

If you're *not* sure if the conversion is possible, use `dynamic_cast` instead: it returns a clean `nullptr`, rather than garbage, if the cast you ask is impossible.

By the way, note that the `identifier()` functions in the derived classes will never be called. Either you store the id in a variable accessible from `Base`, and then you don't need the function in each derived class, or you have to make `identifier()` a virtual function.

Comment: How can he use CRTP if he needs to pass different parameters?

Comment: Having said that, wherever possible it would be preferable to embed the `switch` stuff in the base class and have it decide what to do, rather than putting the responsibility of decoding the derived type at any call site. Perhaps relevant parameters can be stored in the base like Daniel said to facilitate this, but while retaining static polymorphism unlike that answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no :

```
virtual std::string Base::identifier()
```

In this case, when you have a Base* you cant call identifier() on it